# How to move UIBarButtonItem with prefersLargeTitles programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios16, xcode14

I use the `NavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` property in the name and added `rightBarButtonItem`. The whole block of settings of my navigationBar looks like this:

```
private func settingNavigationBar() {
    title = "MoneyCount"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "plus.circle"),
                                                        style: .plain,
                                                        target: self,
                                                        action: #selector(pressedPlusButton))
    
}
```

It looks like this

[image]

[image]

How do I place my `rightBarButtonItem` at the level of my title of `NavigationBar`?

I tried changing the rightBarButtonItem and NavigationBar properties, but nothing helped

Comment: Did you try navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -40) ?

Comment: @FrancisF I try it `Cannot assign to value: 'titlePositionAdjustment' is a method`

Comment: Try this navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(10.0, for: .default) and this is for adjust navigation bar navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(10, for: .default). If this doesn't gets you what you need, it would be better to create a container view with label and button and assign it to titleView

Comment: You can create the custom Navigation Bar can set the way you want